# Python 3.0+ : Trying to restart a section of code through IF statements

Tags: python, loops, scripting

So I'm trying to create a script where the user can input a value (1, 2 or 3 for now), and it provides a math function that can be used to find an answer. But then I want to ask if the user wants to either restart that math function or return to the menu to ask the user to choose a different function.

I've only been studying python for a couple weeks, so I don't really know how to do this, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
choice = int(input("What program would you like to run? \n"))

#chooses one of the programs
recarea = 1
circarea = 2
fah = 3

if choice == 1:

    print("This program calculates the area and perimeter of a rectangle:")

    length = float(input("Type in the length: \n"))
    width = float(input("Type in the width: \n"))
    area = length * width
    perimeter = (2*length)+(2*width)

    print("The area of the rectangle is ","{0:.2f}".format(area),"cm and the perimeter is ","{0:.2f}".format(perimeter),"cm",'\n\n')

    reuse = str(input("Would you like to restart the script ?"))

    if reuse == "Yes" or reuse == "yes" or reuse == "y" or reuse == "Y":
        print("Restarting Script...\n")

    else:
        reuse == "No" or reuse == "no" or reuse == "n" or reuse == "N"
        print("Returning to the menu...\n\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you read up on [Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm). If you had your functionality within one, you could call that function to restart again.

Comment: You need to use a loop; probably a while loop would be best. This is too broad of a question as it is though. Look up loops, and as mentioned above, functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your code up into functions:

```
def main():
    print("What program would you like to run? \n")
    choice = int(input("1 - rectangle area\n2 - circle area\n3 - fah"))
    if choice == 1:
        print("This program calculates the area and perimeter of a rectangle:")
        length = float(input("Type in the length: \n"))
        width = float(input("Type in the width: \n"))
        area = length * width
        perimeter = (2*length)+(2*width)
        print("The area of the rectangle is ","{0:.2f}".format(area),"cm and the perimeter is ","{0:.2f}".format(perimeter),"cm",'\n\n')
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Not implemented.")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Not implemented.")
    else:
        print("I didn't understand that input please type 1, 2 or 3.")
        main()
    askRestart()

def askRestart():
    reuse = str(input("Type 'Y' to restart or 'X' to exit()."))
    if reuse.lower() == 'y':
        main()
    elif reuse.lower() == 'x':
        pass
    else:
        print("I didn't understand that input please type 'Y' or 'X'")
        askRestart()
```

Then call the function to run the program:

```
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply wrap your code inside a `while True:` block. This would repeat the whole segment infinitely.

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("What program would you like to run? \n"))

    #chooses one of the programs
    recarea = 1
    circarea = 2
    fah = 3

    if choice == 1:

        print("This program calculates the area and perimeter of a rectangle:")

        length = float(input("Type in the length: \n"))
        width = float(input("Type in the width: \n"))
        area = length * width
        perimeter = (2*length)+(2*width)

        print("The area of the rectangle is ","{0:.2f}".format(area),"cm and the perimeter is ","{0:.2f}".format(perimeter),"cm",'\n\n')

        reuse = str(input("Would you like to restart the script ?"))

        if reuse == "Yes" or reuse == "yes" or reuse == "y" or reuse == "Y":
            print("Restarting Script...\n")

        else:
            reuse == "No" or reuse == "no" or reuse == "n" or reuse == "N"
            print("Returning to the menu...\n\n")
```

Another, perhaps smarter, option would be to terminate the loop if a certain value is entered. For example, this version would exit if `0` is entered.

```
choice=None
while choice != 0:
    choice = int(input("What program would you like to run? (enter 0 to exit) \n"))

    #chooses one of the programs
    recarea = 1
    circarea = 2
    fah = 3

    if choice == 1:

        print("This program calculates the area and perimeter of a rectangle:")

        length = float(input("Type in the length: \n"))
        width = float(input("Type in the width: \n"))
        area = length * width
        perimeter = (2*length)+(2*width)

        print("The area of the rectangle is ","{0:.2f}".format(area),"cm and the perimeter is ","{0:.2f}".format(perimeter),"cm",'\n\n')

        reuse = str(input("Would you like to restart the script ?"))

        if reuse == "Yes" or reuse == "yes" or reuse == "y" or reuse == "Y":
            print("Restarting Script...\n")

        else:
            reuse == "No" or reuse == "no" or reuse == "n" or reuse == "N"
            print("Returning to the menu...\n\n")
```